# Plot a list of vectors matching pixels of an image

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm currently working with optical flow and I'm struggling with displaying my results.

I possess vectors and was looking forward to plotting them matching their corresponding pixel in an image.

I've tried the function `ListVectorDensityPlot`, but it seems to do its own representation of the data I'm providing.

Some other functions I've tried seem to do the same.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time!

The following is what I've been working with:

```
    (* This is me, generating a random image {21, 21} sized *)
    
    i1big = Blur[RandomImage[{0 - 0.75, 1 + 0.75}, {99,99}], 3];
    
    origin[{x_, y_}] := {x - 0.1, y - 0.1};
    
    i2big = ImageTransformation[i1big, origin, DataRange -> Full, 
       Resampling -> "Cubic", Padding -> "Reflected"];
    
    i1 = ImageTake[
       i1big, {50 - 10, 50 + 10}, {50 - 10, 
        50 + 10}];
    i2 = ImageTake[
       i2big, {50 - 10, 50 + 10}, {50 - 10, 50 + 10}];
    
    (* This is the result vectors I Obtain after calculating the 
    optical flow with my algorithm*)
    
    OFvectors = OpticalFlow[i1, i2]
    Dimensions[OFvectors];
    {19, 19, 2}
    
    (* Being that I possess 1 vector for each pixel 
    (excluding the border of the image) 
    I wanted to display each vector in a grid corresponding to each 
    pixel of the image. Maybe over a grid type of plot?? *)
    
    GridPlot[i1, OFvectors]; (*????*)
```

**Thanks for everyone's help, ended up using this:**

Where `VectorPoints -> All` and Daniel's answer fixed my problem.

```
ListVectorPlot[{ress[[2]], resreal}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[0.2], 
 VectorMarkers -> Placed["Dot", "End"], 
 VectorPoints -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Point /@ resreal[[All, All, 1]]}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
 VectorSizes -> Small,
 VectorStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 4;
 VectorColorFunction -> None
 ]
```

Comment: Please share some data and the code you’ve tried so far. If you have an example of what you want to accomplish from another source, that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Without the definition of `OpticalFlow[]` and `GridPlot[]`, other people won't be able to figure out what's wrong with what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not specify `OpticalFlow`, I make up some data with the same dimensions as you indicate {19,19,2}:

```
dat = Table[{-y, x}, {x, 19}, {y, 19}];
```

The easiest way to plot this is to use `ListVectorPlot`. Unfortunately, this format is not suited for `ListVectorPlot`, which request data of the form: {point,vector}. However, we may use `MapIndexed` to get the data in a format `ListVectorPlot` likes:

```
dat = Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2[[;; 2]], #1} &, dat, {2}], 1];
```

With data in the correct format, we may now use `ListVectorPlot`:

```
ListVectorPlot[dat]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Can i ask you why you placed a negative in "y"?

Comment: No mystery there. I needed to choose some arbitrary vector, so I chose the vector from the origin to the position and turned it by 90 degree to get a circular field.